# Connect to remote MySQL using proxy

Tags: mysql, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to connect to a remote MySQL server (with TCP access limited to a specific IP) using port forwarding via SSH, but still haven't figured out how to do it.

Here's what I intend to do:

```
Local[A] ---> Proxy[B] ---> Remote MySQL[C]
```

[A] Local machine with Windows

[B] CentOS machine with IP 123.123.123.1 (with it's own MySQL running, btw)

[C] Remote MySQL server with IP 123.123.123.1 authorized on port 3306

How to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do machines B and C really have the same IP address?

Comment: Take a look at this question as it's the same concept: http://serverfault.com/questions/134289

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use PuTTY's port forwarding to forward local port 3306 to port 3306 of machine C, connecting to machine B. If using the command line ssh use:

```
ssh -L 3306:machineC:3306 username@machineB
```

then connect to MySQL via `localhost:3306`.